# How to make the scroll VIew scroll in all the direction?

Tags: iphone

My problem goes like this :-

```
{       someview = [[someview1 alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 1024, 1024)) resolution:CGSizeMake(768, 960))];

    scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0,768,960)];
            scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(1024,1024);


     scrollView.bouncesZoom = YES;
        scrollView.pagingEnabled = YES;
        scrollView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        scrollView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = YES;
        scrollView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = YES;  
        scrollView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
        CGRect Frame=rdcview.bounds;
        scrollView.minimumZoomScale = 1.0; 
        scrollView.maximumZoomScale = 2.0;
       [scrollView setDelegate:self];

        [scrollView addSubview:someview1];
        [self.view addSubview:scrollView];
}
```

After all this i rotate my device but the view is not Scrollable in all the Direction ,  plz help me to find the solution .

Note:--it scrolls but not stick their ,when i remove my finger it just come back to previous
position .

Comment: Did you intend to create a view named someview but addSubview:someview1? or is that a typo in your example code?

Comment: Now i am just giving you the example in this code ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have a typo.

Change:

```
[scrollView addSubview:someview1];
```

to:

```
[scrollView addSubview:someview];
```

Comment: thanks but it is not working dude....